# How to use Python/NumPy for a fairly large project?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

So far I've been writing *one-script* Python programs, mainly for text processing and data analysis.

Now I want to bring one of my old Matlab simulation project to Python/NumPy. In that project I have one main program (in a `.m` file) with a few tens of functions (each in a separate `.m` file). There were global variables that were used across all functions so that I don't have to input them as arguments for every function. But then I can't run/test individual function without running the main program, because the global variables will then be undefined, or it calls another function in another file. Plus the file organizing is a mess. It is painful to add new functions, changing existing ones, especially the main program.

This time I want to do things *properly*. I want the program to have a proper *architecture*, if it's the right word. First I need to know to organize all those functions. I don't think each little function having its own file is a good idea. I think maybe I can divide those functions into several groups and each group can be one file? Will it be a `.py` file or some other kind of file? Second I would like it to be easily expandable, that I can add new functions easily.

I believe there must be some standard way of doing this, but I have no clue.

One more question: when I run a Matlab program, after it finishes, I still have all the variables in the *workspace*, so I can still check the numbers, make plots, etc. But when I run my python script through IPython shell, it clears everything afterwards. Is there a similar thing as the *workspace*?

Comment: `python -i script.py` will leave you at the interactive prompt after you run the script.  I don't know about `Ipython`, but I would bet that it behaves the same.

Comment: Depends on the IDE, `Spyder` does have `Variable Explorer` where you can view your variables, though I don't think you can save the workspace like you can in matlab. However, I find that using `print` or `pprint` the most convenient way to view the variables.

Comment: @mgilson - IPython behaves in the same way. :)

Comment: @Talvalin -- drat -- I should have tried to find someone to bet against that.  I could have made some money off that one.

Answer (score 5):

Any time you have a bunch of functions sharing the same global state:

```
foo = 1
def do_something1():
    print foo

def do_something2():
    global foo
    foo += 1
```

you're better off defining a class:

```
class NoGlobal(object):
     """docstring -- Pick a better name for your class please :)"""

     def __init__(self):
          self.foo = 1

     def do_something1(self):
          print self.foo

     def do_something2(self):
          self.foo += 1
```

Now you're not sharing global state and you can run your "simulation" as much as you'd like without mucking about with your globals -- Simply instantiate a new class instance and you're ready to start the new simulation.

As far as leaving it so that you can play around with things after your script terminates, that's what the `-i` option is for:

```
python -i yourscript.py
```

Comment: The global state will be defined in the main function. So in the `__init__` section, can I write `self.foo = foo` where `foo` is defined in the main function?

Comment: @LWZ -- I'm saying that the global state *shouldn't* be defined in the main function.  You should pack it into the class.  if `foo` is the global state, then you could make it an argument to `__init__` -- e.g. `def __init__(self,foo): self.foo = foo`... Then you can pass it when you create your class:  `simulation = NoGlobal(foo)`

Comment: Please forgive me but I'm really confused. What is your `NoGlobal` class for? It seems like it's where I define a bunch of functions, is that right? Is `foo` used only within these functions or shared by ALL functions? And I don't want `foo` to be an argument, because I have too many of them. I need to read upon `class` first...

Comment: @LWZ -- The class removes the need for global data.  The global data you have essentially gets passed into the functions so you don't have to pass it explicitly.  That's what happens with a class when you call a method -- You pass a bunch of state in too.  the difference here is that you can have a bunch of different classes, each holding it's own state where you couldn't have that before.

Answer (score 2):

As for the interactive Python shell: [IPython](http://ipython.org) is very useful if you want to work interactivly in Python.

Started in pylab mode: `ipython --pylab` gives you an interactive python shell with Matlab-like functionality (names in the packages [numpy](http://www.numpy.org) and [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org) already imported in the scope.) You can also save your session or load stored sessions and arbitrary python programs.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found part of what I was looking for, it's asked in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155135/how-to-organize-a-python-project). Things can be organized in Modules (`.py` files) and Packages (folder with `__init__.py` file). In that way I can group a bunch of functions into a *module*, and put all modules for the project in a *package*.

I still need to understand the `class` thing with the global variables.