# How to use __init__.py in (sub-)modules to define namespaces?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, namespaces, python-module

my question is about writing Python (3.x) packages and (sub-)modules and the  correct usage of `__init__.py` files to declare namespaces.
I used to code in C++, so I like to use a lot of separate files to organize projects. For example, (imo) if a module contains several classes, each of these should be in a separate file.

As I am inexperienced developing in Python, it is hard to formulate my thoughts in a  simple question.
So let's consider the following small python package as an example.

## Directory layout

```
dir
 |
 +-- example
 |    |
 |    +-- script.py
 |
 +-- package
      |
      +-- __init__.py
      |
      +-- foo.py
      |
      +-- subpackage
           |
           +-- __init__.py
           |
           +-- bar.py
```

Let's have a look at the files.

## File Content

`package/foo.py`:

```
def foo:
    print('foo')
```

`package/subpackage/bar.py`:

```
def bar:
    print('bar')
```

The following `example/script.py` works fine.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '..')

import package
import package.subpackage


package.foo.foo()
package.subpackage.bar.bar()
```

I don't like to use `package.foo.foo()` / `package.subpackage.bar.bar()` and would like to use `package.foo()` / `package.subpackage.bar()`.

And I don't want to use `from package.subpackage.bar import bar`, as I don't want to mix the namespace of subpackage into script.

## Solution

I used the `__init__.py` files to achieve that.

`package/__init__.py`:

```
from package.foo import foo
```

`package/subpackage/__init__.py`:

```
from package.subpackage.bar import bar
```

## Questions

- Is this a good python-like way to define namespaces? Or is there a better / common way to organize the file-system of a package in python. (I did not find a proper tutorial/example for this.)
- In file `package/subpackage/__init__.py`, why does it have to be:

  `from package.subpackage.bar import bar`

  and not:

  `from subpackage.bar import bar`?

This would result in the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line x, in <module>
import package.subpackage
File "..\package\subpackage\__init__.py", line x, in <module>
from subpackage.bar import bar
ImportError: No module named 'subpackage'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is this a good python-like way to define namespaces? Or is there a better / common way to organize the file-system of a package in python. (I did not find a proper tutorial/example for this.)

This is an *okay* way to setup a Python package. Only *okay* and not 'good' because of the contents of `foo.py` and `bar.py`.

> I don't like to use `package.foo.foo()` / `package.subpackage.bar.bar()` and would like to use `package.foo()` / `package.subpackage.bar()`.

In this case, you can't. And not mixing the name spaces is good reason to not do `from package.subpackage.bar import bar`.

It would have been better if `def foo(): ...` and `def bar(): ...` were directly in `__init__.py`. That way, you could have done `package.foo()` and `package.subpackage.bar()`. It could also have been done by using `__all__` in init but `import *` is also not considered good.

Or, the `foo` and `bar` packages should have had more in it like `foo.function1`, `foo.other_func`, `bar.drink`, etc. which gives it more human-friendly understandable organisation.

Examples and references are not within scope for good StackOverflow questions but here are some, for a well thought-out question:

- [Structuring Your Project — The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/)
- [The Pythonic way of organizing modules and packages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1801878/1431750)
- [How to organize a Python Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5155135/1431750)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Basically your second link ("The Pythonic way ...") is the StackOverflow question I was looking for. 
I don't like the idea of "throwing a ton of code" in one file as the author says. But as Python sees files as modules, there seems to be no good solution. 

 I got the idea of editing `__init__.py`-files [here](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/08/python-201-creating-modules-and-packages/).

Answer (score 6):

The answer to the second question:

> In file `package/subpackage/__init__.py`, why does it have to be:
>
> `from package.subpackage.bar import bar`
>
> and not:
>
> `from subpackage.bar import bar`?

is that you have to use `from .bar import bar`. The dot is used when you want to do relative imports inside a package structure. See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references