# Python 3: How to import from different folder/directories

Tags: python

I’ve been working a lot lately with python 3 and I found that I am unable to import a module from a separate folder. Is there a way to import it while it’s in a folder subdivision? 
To give more context of this issue here is the “launcher” location and folder that I want to access:

```
Launcher.py
Folder
- program-to-import.py
```

That’s the layout. How do I import into launcher from my other module?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: You'd have to start by taking the dashes out of that name. This being python, there is of course a way to import a file with dashes, but it's not something you want to focus on as a beginner.

Comment: I've used my close vote, but any of the following are dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5155135/2988730, https://stackoverflow.com/q/391879/2988730, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1801878/2988730

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to organize a Python Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155135/how-to-organize-a-python-project)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for the research, I've voted as duplicate of the first one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned by others, `-` in name is invalid, try importing after removing them if you have them in your file name. For now, let's call it `program_to_import`

```
from folder import program_to_import
```

And to call a function from `program_to_import`, you use this -

```
program_to_import.function_to_call()
```

Also, it's always a good idea to look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

You could also try by adding an `__init__.py` in your folder. The use of `__init.py__` is as follows -

> The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later (deeper) on the module search path. In the simplest case, **init**.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the **all** variable, described later.

Comment: Does this work without adding `__init__.py` to the `folder`?

Comment: 1/ This wont work if Folder isn't a package. 2/ As already noted by @Mad Physicist,  `-` is forbidden in names.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille `-` in names is asked by the OP

Comment: N@ThatBird No, if `Folder` doesn't contain a `__init__.py` file (even empty), it won't be considered a package, so importing this way wont work. The filename the OP suggests **can't** be used as it contains `-`, so it's important to tell him.

Comment: Created two python files in my machine, one in a directory and one in the level of the directory. Called a function from the python file in the directory

Comment: @ThatBird. Your job is to explain what OP is doing wrong, not excuse your incorrect code by saying "OP did it".

Comment: Also, it's not my **job** now is it?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I understand, and edited the answer

Comment: Not your job per se, but it's presumably the burden you've willingly accepted when you decided to post a good answer :)

Comment: For those of you who want more info, I was using the names as an example. Of course I would never try to use - in my names. I am a novice however. If you wish to see the actual program, it is a huge program (or soon to be at least) that I am slowly working on in my free time. For reference, I used launcher to represent `main.py` and I used program-to-import.py as `LevelLoader.py`    I also have subfolders and I am going to have to use the `__init__.py` for that. Anyways, here is the link... please don't criticize me on it. https://repl.it/@SilverGaming/DandD-project

Answer (score -1):

Python supports importing from child paths rather trivially.
in Launcher.py enter the following.

```
from Folder.program-to-import import *
```

Comment: 1/ This wont work if `Folder` isn't a package. 2/ Importing * is usually discouraged.

Comment: Also, using - in a package or module name is prohibited for obvious reasons.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The name was took from his example, I am well aware that a - should not be used. -ThierryLathuille This does work even if Folder is not a package. Import * is discouraged although the user did not state what the structure of the folder to be imported was so * was used.

Comment: Thank so for the answer. After a little work I modified all the program and got it working. I have been working with python for a rather short time so I hope you all can understand why I am a little on the unknowledgeable side of things.